# Kernel memory leak detector

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, memory-leak-detector, kmem

I have enable the "Kernel memory leak detector" option inside kernel hacking and rebuilt/reboot the system, for now the kmemleak file exists inside the `/sys/kernel/debug` folder but seems like I cannot trigger the scan by `echo scan > /sys/kernel/debug/kmemleak`, I have mounted debugfs onto `/sys/kernel/debug`, but when I try to trigger the scan it gives me

```
-bash: echo: write error: Device or resource busy
```

My guessing is that this is because I do not have write permission inside /sys folder even I'm a root user. Any suggestion how to solve this issue?

Comment: The kmemleak sysfs write handler returns `EBUSY` if kmemleak is disabled. Did you turn off kmemleak by echo-ing `off`? If not, is the Linux kernel built with `CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_DEFAULT_OFF=y` ? Have you tried booting `kmemleak=on` passed on the Linux kernel bootargs/cmdline?

Comment: I did not echo off, the CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_DEFAULT_OFF is not set (I have checked my .config file), also I have tried reboot "kmemleak=on" and I did "echo scan > /sys/kernel/debug/kmemleak" as soon as I rebooted, but it still gives me same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check few things when using kmemleak.

Check whether any bootargs or commandline parameter `kmemleak=off` is    being passed.

In your boot log, check if you have got any kmemleak    related logs, especially something like below logs

```
kmemleak: Kernel memory leak detector disabled
kmemleak: Early log buffer exceeded (919), please increase DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_EARLY_LOG_SIZE
```

Most probably, I think you need to configure `CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_EARLY_LOG_SIZE`. If during boot, the log size for kmemleak increases beyond the limit set in linux kernel config, kmemleak is disabled.

So, configure `CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_EARLY_LOG_SIZE` and increase the size. This option is also under `kernel hacking`. I am using kernel source 4.19.9 and attaching the screenshot for reference. `Maximum kmemleak early log entries` is the field, you may need to set it to some higher value(e.g 4096).

[image]

Comment: Btw, CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_EARLY_LOG_SIZE was renamed to CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_MEM_POOL_SIZE in 5.5. Also, i found that explicitly passing kmemleak=on solved the issue at hand...